# Pandas remove duplicate rows by time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe that represents a service history:

```
                  Start                    End        ContactName      Agente      Code
0   2020-05-05 11:52:34    2020-05-05 18:03:15      473000 Carlos   Pedro BRA    473000
1   2020-05-05 15:39:06    2020-05-05 18:03:09    580000 Rosineia   Pedro BRA    580000
2   2020-05-05 17:47:59    2020-05-05 18:03:06   2038000 Mauricio   Pedro BRA   2038000
3   2020-05-05 17:43:46    2020-05-05 18:02:58   3975000 - Sergio   Pedro BRA   3975000
4   2020-05-05 15:34:44    2020-05-05 17:52:17   3388000  Rodrigo   Pedro BRA   3388000
5   2020-05-05 15:34:43    2020-05-05 17:52:14            4077000   Pedro BRA   4077000
6   2020-05-05 17:45:24    2020-05-05 17:52:08  2064000 Cleberson   Pedro BRA   2064000
7   2020-05-05 18:20:24    2020-05-05 18:25:00  2064000 Cleberson   Pedro BRA   2064000
```

I want to remove calls that occurred from the same customer to the same agent within the range of one hour, example:

- cleberson (last line) started an appointment at 17:45 with agent
  pedro and finished at 17:52
- shortly thereafter (IN LESS THAN AN HOUR) he started another service 
  that was also finished in less than an hour

I would like to keep only one attendance record if more than one occurs within an hour

thanks for the help, i tried all the ways but i couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following strategy should resolve your issue:

1. Sort the dataframe by columns: ContactName, Agente, Start. You should now have all instances of the same client, contacting the same agent with ascending start times.
2. You can use the pandas shift operator to create your contact name, agente and start columns shifted by one - effectively creating new columns that allow you to compare each row to the previous row (example use - df['ContactName'].shift(1)). You can now use boolean masking to create a column that depends on these new columns to mark rows you want to identify.

Loosely based on your data in psuedocode-

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['ContactName', 'Angente', 'Start'])
mask = (df['ContactName'] == df['ContactName'].shift(1)) & (df['Agente'] == df['Agente'].shift(1)) & (abs(df['Start'] - df['Start'].shift(1)) < pd.Timedelta('1 hour')) # select rows that have the same contact, agent as the previous row as well as started with less than 1 hour difference
df.loc[mask, 'to_remove'] = True 
df = df[~df['to_remove'] # filter out redundant values
```